# Incorrect Output Values using Chudnovsky Algorithm Python

Tags: python

I was writing a small program in Python to calculate n digits of pi using mpmath, I don't know what's going when i run test case for 30 decimal places, I  get incorrect value for pi

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm

```
from mpmath import *


def PI(n):

 mp.dps = 30
 C = 426880* sqrt(10005)
 K, M, X, L, S = mpf(6), mpf(1), mpf(1), mpf(13591409), mpf(13591409)

 for k in range(1, 15):
   L += 545140134
   X *= -262537412640768000  
   K += 12
   M = M * ((K**3 - 16*K)/((k+1)**3))
   S += (M*L) / mpf(X)

 pi = C / mpf(S)
 nprint(pi,n+1)

PI(30)
```

The result shows like this 3.141592653590075110504899668497

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors. Firstly, in your loop, you have hardcoded the limit for k = 15. I suspect that should be `for k in range(1, n+1)`. Secondly, looking at the algorithm (and the python implementation in the article!) I think the order of operations might be wrong.

```
from mpmath import *


def PI(n):
    mp.dps = 30
    C = 426880 * sqrt(10005)
    K, M, X, L, S = mpf(6), mpf(1), mpf(1), mpf(13591409), mpf(13591409)
    for k in range(1, n+1):
        M = (K ** 3 - 16 * K) * M / k ** 3
        L += 545140134
        X *= -262537412640768000
        S += (M * L) / mpf(X)
        K += 12


    pi = C / mpf(S)
    nprint(pi, n + 1)


PI(30)
# Output = 3.141592653589793238462643383279
```

Comparing with value from here: http://www.eveandersson.com/pi/digits/pi-digits?n_decimals_to_display=30&breakpoint=10

> 3.141592653589793238462643383279

---

Let's walk through both the algorithm and code and compare values at each stage. Perhaps that will be helpful to see why the Python code divides by `k^3` not `(k+1)^3`.

From the Wikipedia article:

[image]

Let's calculate the first couple of values:

[image]

Now compare that to the code, concentrating on the values of k, K and M only:

```
    for k in range(1, n+1):
        M = (K ** 3 - 16 * K) * M / k ** 3
        K += 12
```

Initially:

> k = 1, K = 6, M = 1

[image]

> k = 2, K = 6, M = 120

[image]

Hopefully, this shows why the code divides by `k^3`, it is a matter of indexing.

Comment: In calculating M, why does k in the denominator becomes k ** 3 from (k+1) ** 3  in your code, even in wikipedia, and i don't understand why they use floor division.

Comment: @KushalGopal, I have edited my answer to give more explanation.

Comment: @ L.Clarkson Thank you for clarifying my doubts, you've been very helpful.

Comment: Furthermore, if you used `for k in range(0, n)` I suspect you would then have to use k + 1 instead of k